# ExpressionEngine plugin return json data

Tags: json, expressionengine

In the plugin I use:

```
$this->return_data = json_encode(array('loggedin' => $LoggedIn, 'Cust_ID' => $Participant_ID));
```

In the template I call it like this

```
$custinfo = {exp:user_loggedin};
```

It returns it like this:

```
$custinfo = {"loggedin":"no","Cust_ID":-1};
```

And I get this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(642) : eval()'d code on line 656
```

If I use

```
$custinfo = json_decode({exp:user_loggedin})
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(642) : eval()'d code on line 656
```

Any ideas??

Comment: This could be a parse order issue.  Do you have PHP parsing on input or output?

Comment: Output in the template where this code is being used.

Comment: Changing to Input doesn't help, same errors.

Comment: We are dropping usage of this plugin and using cookies instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to quote your variable:

`$custinfo = "{exp:user_loggedin}";`

Comment: This is what is returned: $custinfo = "{"loggedin":"no","Cust_ID":-1}";

Comment: Is PHP set to parse on input or output? If you're already using a custom plugin, can you move whatever else you're doing with PHP in your template to another method in that same plugin? You can avoid many parse order issues this way.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the Magento code we are using in the plugin. We have several plugins that use the EXACT same code to load Magento objects but don't exhibit this problem.

Comment: We are dropping the usage of this plugin and using cookies instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have having a combination of parse order issues and quoting issues.

Let's say you are handling PHP on Output.

1. plugin will run
2. then regular EE code
3. then PHP

Derek, recognizing the quote problem, suggested:

```
$custinfo = "{exp:user_loggedin}";
```

But wouldn't that translate to the following code at stage 3?

```
$custinfo = "{"loggedin":"no","Cust_ID":-1}";
```

Does that look like valid PHP code to you?  Doesn't to me.

You are either going to have to escape those quotes or use a HEREDOC or something…

```
$custinfo = <<<HEREDOC
{"loggedin":"no","Cust_ID":-1}
HEREDOC;
```

Comment: We are dropping the usage of this plugin and using cookies instead.